# How do i Access the keys of a JSON Object in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, mqtt

I am receiving Data from an MQTT Server, which is giving me data after some intervals. The Data received is in the form of JSON Object. I want to store the values of the data that I  get and then pass it to my Database. But I am getting error Accessing its Keys.

This is my Function which is fetching the JSON Data.

```
function mqtt_messsageReceived(topic, message, packet) {


    if(message !== null && message !== undefined )
    {
        var myMessages = message;
       console.log('Messages are '+ myMessages);


    }

};
```

This is my Console Log JSON  Data.

```
Messages are {"Temp":26.50,"Door":1,"Fan1":0,"Fan2":0,"Time":"22-8-2018 16:05","mac":"5ccf7f5a4ba4"}
```

I Want to access Temp from this JSON Object.

I have tried doing :

```
console.log('Temp is '+myMessages.Temp);
```

But it only gives me an Error - Temp is undefined.
I have Tried Fetching many ways, one way was with  Object.values

```
var myMessages = Object.values(message);
```

All I get is some random numbers

```
My  Messages are 123,34,84,101,109,112,34,58,50,52,46,53,48,44,34,68,111,111,114,34,58,49,44,34,70,97,110,49,34,58,48,44,34,70,97,110,50,34,58,49,44,34,84,105,109,101,34,58,34,50,50,45,56,45,50,48,49,56,32,49,54,58,49,54,34,44,34,109,97,99,34,58,34,53,99,99,102,55,102,53,97,52,98,97,52,34,125,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
```

Can anyone Help here ??

Comment: look at [`JSON.parse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse)

Comment: [There's no such thing as a "JSON Object"](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/)

Comment: @jonatjano i found the solution to this. the JSON which was being received had some hidden special characters had to clean those characters. and no JSON.parse is working properly. and i am able to get obj.Temp and other values.

Comment: I indicated it because there was no visible call to It in your question so I wasn't even sure you called it somewhere before, don't forget to include it next time, seems like @JasminMistry made the same assumption

Answer (score -2):

You can use JSON.parse:

```
console.log(JSON.parse(myMessages)["Temp"]);
```

Comment: `myMessages.Temp` and `myMessages["Temp"]` are equivalent. If one is `undefined` then so is the other.

Comment: In general, you should explain why the change you recommend will fix the problem and not just post code with which people can play spot-the-difference. Unfortunately, the difference here doesn't fix the problem.

Comment: its still logging "undefined". both ways i have tried. even storing it in a seperate variable i have tried.